# ZendeskR Producing the following error when trying to connect to api

Tags: r, api, zendesk

I am fairly new to using APIs and trying to use the zendesk API now through R using the `ZendeskR` package. I belive I have connected to it however I keep getting the following error whenever I try to query it.

Here is my code:

```
library(zendeskR)
library(rjson)
zendesk(username, password, url)
ticket <- getTicket('20150')
```

The username, password and url are all variables that I have assigned the correct values.

The following error that I get when I run it is this:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Please help as I am unsure on what this error means or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS v1.1 is no longer accepted by Zendesk, please use TLS v1.2.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by this? Thanks

Comment: I've had a look into it and understand it now, however how would I go about changing the version of TLS used?

Comment: You need to upgrade SSL related libraries. Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can do this or the maintainer of zendeskR needs to, I did notice it was last updated in 2014...

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking, no worries though thanks for responding! I've managed to work around it I believe

Comment: @MatthewMeek how did you go about it?

Comment: @user322203 we ended up not using zendesk anymore so the project was no longer needed. Pretty sure at the time I didnt have the time to configure a workaround so just left the project alone. Sorry that wasn't very helpful for you!

Comment: thanks @MatthewMeek i have since made my own work around